# Kivy ScrollView does not fill the entire window

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to write a Kivy file that includes a scrollview below the MDToolBar and above MDBottomNavigation. I cannot get the ScrollView content to fill the entire screen below the ToolBar and above the BottomNav. It only fills have the window vertical span. If I eliminate the toolbar and bottom nave the scrollview fills the entire vertical span without a problem. Any tips on getting the scrollview contents to fill the completely would be appreciated. I tried changing indentation and that did not work. Thanks in advance.

Screenshot[image]

```
# WINDOW MANAGER

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    AboutWindow:

<MainWindow>:

    name: "main"

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            title: "Solar Weather"


        MDLabel:
            id: sub_title 
            text: "SUB TITLE" 
            halign: "center"
            size_hint: (1,0.2)

        ScrollView:

            size: self.size

            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: self.minimum_width
                cols: 2
                spacing: "20dp"
                padding: "20dp"

                # SOLAR FLUX BOX #

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                    MDLabel:
                        id: flux
                        text: "Solar Wind"
                        halign: "center"

                    MDLabel:
                        id: flux_value_id
                        text: ""
                        halign: "center"

                    MDLabel:
                        id: flux_time_id
                        text: ""
                        halign: "center"

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Refresh"
                        pos_hint: {"x":0}
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release: root.calc_solar_flux()

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Details"
                        pos_hint: {"x":0}
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release: root.calc_solar_flux()
                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Solar Wind"
                        halign: "center"

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Go Back"
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release:
                            root.manager.current = "main"
                            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"



        MDBottomNavigation:

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'Dark'
                text: "Dark Theme"
                icon: 'brightness-2'
                on_tab_release: root.dark_theme() 

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'Light'
                text: "Light Theme"
                icon: 'brightness-5'
                on_tab_release: root.light_theme() 

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'info'
                text: "About"
                icon: 'information'
                on_tab_release: 
                    root.manager.current = "about"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'option 2'
                text: "Relaod"
                icon: 'reload'





#: include about.kv
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else. I had to rewrite the kv file fairly extensively but it works.

```
# WINDOW MANAGER

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    AboutWindow:

<MainWindow>:

    name: "main"

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:
            id: title 
            text: "SOLAR WEATHER" 
            halign: "left"
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            padding_x: 20
            pos_hint: {"x":0.0,"y":0.9}
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark

        MDLabel:
            id: sub_title 
            text: "SUB TITLE" 
            halign: "center"
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.0,"y":0.8}


        ScrollView:

            size: self.size
            pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0.1}

            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: None 
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: self.minimum_width
                cols: 2
                spacing: "20dp"
                padding: "20dp"

                # SOLAR FLUX BOX #

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    spacing: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                    MDLabel:
                        id: flux
                        text: "SOLAR FLUX"
                        halign: "center"

                    MDLabel:
                        id: flux_value_id
                        markup: True
                        text: ""
                        halign: "center"

                    MDLabel:
                        id: flux_time_id
                        text: ""
                        halign: "center"
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Refresh"
                        pos_hint: {"x":0}
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release: root.calc_solar_flux()

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Details"
                        pos_hint: {"x":0}
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release: root.calc_solar_flux()

            # SUN SPOT NUMBER BOX #

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    spacing: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                    MDLabel:
                        id: ssn 
                        text: "SUN SPOT NUMBER"
                        halign: "center"

                    MDLabel:
                        id: ssn_value_id
                        markup: True
                        text: ""
                        halign: "center"
                    MDLabel:
                        id: ssn_date_id
                        text: ""
                        halign: "center"

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Refresh"
                        pos_hint: {"x":0}
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release: root.calc_sunspot_number()

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Details"
                        pos_hint: {"x":0}
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release: root.calc_sunspot_number()

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                MDCard:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "8dp"
                    spacing: "8dp"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: "210dp"
                    elevation: 5

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Solar Wind"
                        halign: "center"

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "Go Back"
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        on_release:
                            root.manager.current = "main"
                            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        GridLayout:

            size_hint_y: None 
            height: self.minimum_height
            width: self.minimum_width
            cols: 3 
            spacing: "80dp"
            padding: "20dp"
            MDIconButton:
                name: "Dark" 
                text: "Dark Theme" 
                icon: "brightness-2"
                on_release: root.dark_theme()
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark

            MDIconButton:
                id: light_theme_icon
                name: "Light" 
                text: "Light Theme" 
                icon: "brightness-5"
                on_release: root.light_theme()
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark

            MDIconButton:
                name: "info" 
                text: "About" 
                icon: "information"
                on_release: 
                    root.manager.current = "about"
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark

#: include about.kv
```